# How to make `helm-execute-persistent-action` not to follow symlink original path

Tags: emacs, helm

I want to complete by `Tab` when using `find-file`, so I bind a function `helm-execute-persistent-action` to `Tab` like this.

```
;; For find-file etc.
(define-key helm-read-file-map (kbd "TAB") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
;; For helm-find-files etc.
(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "TAB") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
```

This is much better for me. But there is small problem still, the function expand symlink to original path.

Is there option to disable expanding symbolic link?